# cron4j: Schedule multiple tasks with different schedule time

Tags: java, cron4j

I don't have experience with cron4j scheduler and I need to schedule tasks with different time. Use cron4j is requirement, so I have to use it. I've tried to find tutorial but unsuccessfully. Can someone help me. I don't want full code here now, just recommendation how to do that or link with tutorial. I've read cron4j documentation, but I've not found what I need. I appreciate every help. Thanks.

Comment: I believe the documentation has more than enough to cover cron4j usage. What exactly do you need to do that you can't find in the documentations ?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I'm late to the party.

This is exactly the question I struggled with on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18814915/using-cron4j-i-have-separate-tasks-that-need-separate-schedules)

However I managed to find 'a' way to implement multiple schedules.

If you have different tasks you want to execute at different times. Create different schedulers:

```
// Creates a Constituent Scheduler instance.
Scheduler myFirstScheduler = new Scheduler();

// Creates a Summary Scheduler instance.

Scheduler mySecondScheduler = new Scheduler();

// Schedule a once-a-week task at 8am on Sunday.        
myFirstScheduler("0 8 * * 7", new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //DO SOMETHING

    }
});


//Schedule a twice a day task at 7am and 6pm on weekdays
mySecondScheduler("0 7 * * 1-5 |0 18 * * 1-5 ", new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //DO SOMETHING
    }
});
```

Comment: No need to make separate objects. You can call schedule() method multiple times with different schedule time specified.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/cron4j/manual.php?PHPSESSID=joa7htq52ntatnb3012dutdc54) cron4j documentation. There are code samples also. In general scheduling is done through call to `Scheduler#schedule` method which accept String in linux `cron` format e.g. `* * * * *`